# How can I implement this method in swift from obj-c protocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have tried numerous ways of phrasing this protocol implementation in swift and the compiler refuses them all!

Objective C protocol:

```
@protocol QBRTCClientDelegate <NSObject>


/**
 *  Called when started new session with you
 *
 *  @param session  QBWebRTCSession instance
 *  @param userInfo The user information dictionary for the new session. May be nil.
 */
- (void)didReceiveNewSession:(QBRTCSession *)session userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;

@optional
/**
 * Called when you called to user, but user does not respond
 * use +[QBRTCConfig setAnswerTimeInterval:value] to set answer time interval
 * default value: 45 seconds
 * @param userID ID of opponent
 */
- (void)session:(QBRTCSession *)session userDoesNotRespond:(NSNumber *)userID;

...
```

Swift implementation:

```
class QuickbloxManager: NSObject, QBRTCClientDelegate {
    func didReceiveNewSession(session: QBRTCSession, userInfo: NSDictionary) -> Void {

    }
    ...
```

Compiler tells me that the implementing class does not conform to the protocol so I must be doing something wrong!

Comment: Does protocol have other required or optional methods?

Comment: If you remove the ! what does it say?

Comment: @Avt - yes there are a lot of other optional methods but this is the only required one (I actually modified the protocol to make this required because I sensed it wasn't actually working as expected). If I try making other methods in the protocol required and this one optional it works fine...

Comment: @Aggressor - I tried all 4 permutations of ! removal and they all fail with the same error.

Comment: What is the original definition of the Objective-C protocol? If it has the `<NSObject>` bit, your Swift class has to extend `NSObject` in addition to the protocol itself.

Comment: have you tired adding @objc beside the function name?

Comment: @ArnoldSakhnov I have added more context -- it does have an NSObject reference. I have the NSObject as the base class on my swift class though.

Comment: You need - `(void)session:(QBRTCSession *)session userDoesNotRespond:(NSNumber *)userID;` covered in swift as well

Comment: @Aggressor Please note that that function is marked as optional in the objective C protocol -- is that still necessary?

Comment: Add `@objc` to class definition. So you will have `@objc class QuickbloxManager: NSObject, QBRTCClientDelegate`

Comment: If you look at the error in the issue navigator in Xcode, you should be able to click on the small grey arrow to the left of the error to get an expanded explanation — this should tell you what the compiler is expecting and what it is missing.

Comment: @Rupert Wow, never knew about that, thank you! It looks like it's complaining about the NSDictionary argument matching -- it says it needs a type of [NSObject: AnyObject]!. I will try this out

Comment: @NedRockson it sounds like that is Swift auto-magically converting the `NSDictionary` to its Swift equivalent of `[NSObject: AnyObject]`

Comment: @Rupert Ah interesting -- I would like to learn more about this but the last 5 minutes of google searching hasn't turned much up. This appears to be a strange edge case... Thank you very much for the information about the compiler error issues though -- this will speed up my development immensely!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to help in the comments I was able to discover that the issue had to do with a mismatch in the NSDictionary type. According to the compiler details, the actual error was:

> Protocol requires function 'didReceiveNewSession(_:userInfo:)' with
>   type '(QBRTCSession!, userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void'

Which means that the mapping to NSDictionary was not correct and instead had to be of type `Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>!`. Thus, the new function declaration in swift is:

```
func didReceiveNewSession(session: QBRTCSession!, userInfo: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>!) -> Void {

    }
```

Which compiles without error.

Comment: In the future, you should post those compiler messages.

Comment: @Aggressor Will do! Just learned about them -- Rupert helped me discover how to find them and that was the breakthrough I needed.